# xsl:number increments when xsl:for-each iteration is skipped

Tags: java, xml, xslt, soap

I have the XML message:

```
<DataList>
    <Datainfo>                  
        <Name>Doc_image.jpg</Name>              
        <Type>Image</Type>                                      
    </Datainfo>

    <Datainfo>                  
        <Name>Spec_text1.txt</Name>             
        <Type>Document</Type>                                           
    </Datainfo>

    <Datainfo>                  
        <Name>Spec_text2.txt</Name>             
        <Type>Document</Type>                                           
    </Datainfo>
</DataList>
```

Which should be transformed to another XML with 2 requirements:

- Only those `<Datainfo>` blocks where *Type = 'Document'*.
- Not more that 5 blocks in total. (For that purpose I used xsl:number as counter)

My XSL is:

```
<xsl:template match="//*:DataList">
<xsl:for-each select="./*:Datainfo[./*:Type = 'Document']">
    <xsl:variable name="num">
        <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="$num &lt;= 5">
        <xsl:element name="Name{$num}">
            <xsl:value-of select="./*:Name"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The first block with Type Image is skipped, but counter still considers this iteration and increments anyway! Now I get this:

```
<Name2>Spec_text1.txt</Name2>
<Name3>Spec_text2.txt</Name3>
```

The expected result is:

```
<Name1>Spec_text1.txt</Name1>
<Name2>Spec_text2.txt</Name2>
```

I got stuck here, because as I understand I can't create my own counter and increment/decrement it whenever I want, like in Java.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `<xsl:for-each select="./*:Datainfo[./*:Type = 'Document'][position() le 5]">` and `<xsl:element name="Name{position()}">`.